# Angular route issue with new created electron-forge project

Tags: angular, electron

Environment

- electron-forge, 5.1.1
- electron-compile, 6.4.2
- angular, 5.2.9

Steps

- Created the electron project with forge template. And everything works.

  - `npm install -g electron-forge`
  - `electron-forge init my-new-project --template=angular2`
  - `cd my-new-project`
  - `npm start`
- Created the angular project with cli in separate folder, and angular is up and running in browser.
- Migrated the angular files under the src folder in electron project.
- Added angular related denpendencies in electron project, such like @angular/router.
- By now with these files under src folder, the electron app runs great.
- index.ts
- index.html
- bootstrap.ts
- app.component.ts
- app.component.html
- app.component.css
- app.module.ts
- Then I just added these files

  - app-routing.module.ts
  - roles

    - roles.module.ts
    - roles-routing.module.ts
    - roles.component.ts
    - roles.component.html
- Update these files

  - index.html with `<base href="">` in the head section.
  - app-routing.module.ts with loadChildren property.
    const routes: Routes = [
                    {
                        path: 'roles',
                        loadChildren: 'roles/roles.module#RolesModule'
                    },
                {
                        path: '',
                    redirectTo: 'roles',
                    pathMatch: 'full'
                }
            ];
  - roles-routing.module.ts
    const routes: Routes = [
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: RolesComponent,
                }
            ];

All these changes all working with angular along in the browser but error in electron app.

**Error: Reference error. System is not defined.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I setup the angular route without feature module and lazy loading, it works. Without feature module, I have to delcare all components in AppModule and use them in AppRoutingModule. It is definitely terrible. Can someone help confirm that Electron does not support angular feature module, please?

Comment: I just retried. Electron supports Angular feature module. But does not support the lazy loading of the route of feature module. Something like loadChildren: 'users/users.module#UsersModule'. :-(

Comment: Electron does not support the lazy loading. Also you have to set the template url like this templateUrl: './roles/roles.component.html'. You have to include the subfolder name. This is the root cause.